# -I Flag in GCC ( Linux )

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

I Have found a source file bundle with a Makefile, I went through it, and In CFLAG Variable, There is a FLAG -I , I have searched on the web, But couldn't find what it actually does. Is it something relevent to the library files included in the C file? ( stdio.h,unistd.h, pthread.h )

Please point me to a source or explain in brief, What does the Flag -I does?

-Regards

Comment: It instructs the compiler to add the argument of the flag `-I` to the include files search path. In Unix/Linux world you typically start from `man gcc` when need to find about comand line flags of `gcc`. Google is not the right tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's right there in the man page of `gcc` (called with `man gcc` on unix/linux [or you can find it via Google](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)):

> **-I** *dir*
>
> Add the directory *dir* to the list of directories to be searched for header files.  Directories named by **-I** are searched before the standard system include directories.  If the directory *dir* is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated .  If *dir* begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see **--sysroot** and **-isysroot**.

(The exact text and semantics may differ between versions of gcc)

Alternatively there is also the gcc documentation online: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ The option for version 4.8.2, as an example, can be found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: Thanks, I understood. Can you tell me how could we use 'man' to search about the flag? I mean, I have tried 'man -I', 'man I', It did not help.

Comment: @Fawzan It's `man gcc` and a long manual will open, in there all options are listed. Instead of `gcc` you can also use this for most other commands.

Comment: Cool , I have used that. and yeah I got a long page. May be we can use grep or something to search in the man page. :)

Comment: to search inside man type / followed by the regex and press enter, press n to go to the next search term in your case it would be "/-l "

Comment: Usually `man` uses `less` to show the man pages, so with `man less` you can learn how to navigate and search in there ;D. RomanATaycher's comment explains how to do a search though.