# Compile hiredis in C on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, redis, hiredis

I'm trying to compile a client using `hiredis` in `C` on `Mac OS X`.

I've installed `hiredis` with:

```
brew install hiredis
```

But still get the error:

```
fatal error: 'hiredis.h' file not found
```

My `hiredis.h` is however in:

```
/usr/local/include/hiredis/hiredis.c
```

How do I tell the compiler this?

I'm compiling with:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/), and in general search for options or flags to add non-standard directories to be searched for header files.

Comment: (a) Your question states that “hiredis.h” is in “/usr/local/include/hiredis/hiredis.c”, but the latter ends in “.c” whereas the former ends in “.h”. (b) Your question does not show the source code that generates the error message. If it says `#include <hiredis.h>`, then the solution may be to change it to `#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>`.

Comment: Thank you, seems to work `gcc redistest.c -o redistest -I /usr/local/include/hiredis/ -lhiredis`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `/usr/local/include` is generally one of the standard directories searched for headers, and it is more commonly intended one use `#include <name/name.h>` to access headers organized by subdirectory than that one add subdirectory paths to the search list.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've been using quite a few Linux systems (and some SunOS systems way before that) where it wasn't. macOS might be different?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Even so, one would want to add just one path, /usr/local/include, to the search list and use `#include <subdirectory/header.h>` in the source rather than add dozens of different subdirectories to the search path.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's true.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you said `hiredis.h` is in `/usr/local/include/hiredis/hiredis.c`, which doesn't really make any sense.

Assuming you meant that your `hiredis.h` is in `/usr/local/include/hiredis`. You can do like:

```
gcc test.c -I/usr/local/include/hiredis -o test
```

Read about `-I` in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143781/i-flag-in-gcc-linux).

UPDATE:

As mentioned by @EricPostpischil in comments, its a better idea to just include like:

```
#include < hiredis/hiredis.h>
```

I am still not sure if `/usr/local/include` is in default include path. If it is, well no need to do anything, just compile like:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

and if it isn't,

```
gcc test.c -I/usr/local/include -o test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `hiredis` with **homebrew**, you can see what's in the package like this:

```
brew ls --verbose hiredis
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/CHANGELOG.md
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/.brew/hiredis.rb
...
...
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/lib/libhiredis.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/lib/pkgconfig/hiredis.pc    <--- PKG-CONFIG
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/lib/libhiredis.a
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/lib/libhiredis.0.14.dylib
...
...
```

And, as you can see, it gives you a `pkg-config` file with all the settings in it that you need. So, you might as well install `pkg-config` and do it properly!

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Now, if you want to know the C compiler flags for `hiredis`, you do:

```
pkg-config --cflags hiredis
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/include/hiredis
```

And if you want to know the linker settings, you do:

```
pkg-config --libs hiredis
-L/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.14.0/lib -lhiredis
```

And so, your compile-link command becomes very simple and updates itself when you update the packages:

```
gcc-9 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs hiredis) -o program program.c
```