# How to create a static library out of many .c and .h files using Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

I am trying to create a static library out of [Trezor Firmware's Crypto Module](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/tree/master/crypto). I was trying to write a Makefile in order to do that, but I am not sure on how to define the order of compilation in Makefile. The make is failing for the following.

Makefile -

```
CC = gcc
AR = ar
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -pedantic

SRC_DIR = trezor-firmware/crypto
BUILD_DIR = build
LIB_DIR = lib

# List all the .c files in the source directory
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# Derive object file names from the source file names
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

# The target library name
LIB_NAME = libcrypto.a

# The final path of the library
LIB_PATH = $(LIB_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)

# Default target
all: $(LIB_PATH)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.h)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Rule to create the library
$(LIB_PATH): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^

# Clean build artifacts
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o $(LIB_PATH)
```

When I execute, it throws the following error -

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -c trezor-firmware/crypto/bip32.c -o build/bip32.o
In file included from trezor-firmware/crypto/bip32.h:31:0,
                 from trezor-firmware/crypto/bip32.c:32:
trezor-firmware/crypto/ed25519-donna/ed25519.h:4:21: fatal error: options.h: No such file or directory
 #include "options.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/bip32.o] Error 1
```

Can someone please help me out on this?

I tried adding `$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.h)` so that all the header files are also taken into consideration but it didn't help. Someone I feel that this is related to dependencies of internal .c files not getting configured in the right order.

Comment: "options.h" is imported in one of the files and yes it is present in the `crypto` folder that I mentioned. I have to add it to `-I` path. I was not doing that.

Comment: Okay. I will try that now and will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that GCC cannot find `options.h`. In addition to being present and readable, the file's path must be added to the compiler's include path. Effectively, this tells the compiler where to look for `#include`'ed files.

In the linked project's `Makefile`, this is accomplished by adding [the current directory with `-I.`](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/blob/92045275fb79e532a5b9a86732c1b3206ef3bba4/crypto/Makefile#L78).

Also see [-I Flag in GCC ( Linux )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143781/i-flag-in-gcc-linux)

Comment: This did solve the problem but a new error came up for me and I think it is due to wrong building of static library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345362/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-error-when-using-mnemonic-to-seed-of-crypto-m